# Web Serial API - problem when stream consists of mix of ASCII and raw data

Tags: javascript, serial-port

I'm trying to parse the following serial input raw data:

```
[51,45,51,30,33,30,33,00,00,00,C0,50,17,FE,05,00,00,58,02,9A,0E,00,00,00,00,02,00,0D,0A]
```

It consist of some chars(0X51,0x45,0x51...) and some raw data (0x00,0x00,0xC0...) and it ends with '\r\n' (0x0D,0x0A).
The end result I'm getting is ('\r\n' is not included):

```
['51','45','51','30','33','30','33','0','0','0','fffd','50','17','fffd','5','0','0','58','2','fffd','e','0','0','0','0','2','0']
```

The values in index 10,13,19 (C0,FE,9A) are not displayed correctly (because they are not part of the ASCII table?). 

To get the data I use TextDecoderStream, and I'm not sure it's the right decoder, although the data is partially comprised of ASCII chars and ends with '\r\n'.
Is there more suitable decoder or there is an error in my code?
Thanks in advance.

```
 // request & open port here.
 port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
 await port.open({
   baudrate: 115200,
   baudRate: 115200,
   dataBits: 8,
   stopBits: 1,
   parity: "none",
   flowControl: "none",
 });
 // setup the output stream here.
 const encoder = new TextEncoderStream();
 outputDone = encoder.readable.pipeTo(port.writable);
 outputStream = encoder.writable;

 /**********************************/
 // code to read the stream here.
 let decoder = new TextDecoderStream();
 inputDone = port.readable.pipeTo(decoder.writable);
 inputStream = decoder.readable.pipeThrough(
   new TransformStream(new LineBreakTransformer())
 );
 
 reader = inputStream.getReader();
 readLoop();
}

/**
* Reads data from the input stream and displays it on screen.
*/
async function readLoop() {
 let i = 0;
 while (true) {
   const { value, done } = await reader.read();
   if (value) {
     let arrValue = [...value];
     ascii_to_hexa(arrValue);
     console.log(arrValue);
     if (done) {
       console.log("[readLoop] DONE", done);
       reader.releaseLock();
       break;
     }
   }
 }
}

class LineBreakTransformer {
 constructor() {
   // A container for holding stream data until a new line.
   this.container = "";
 }

 transform(chunk, controller) {
   // Handle incoming chunk
   this.container += chunk;
   const lines = this.container.split("\r\n");
   this.container = lines.pop();
   lines.forEach((line) => controller.enqueue(line));
 }

 flush(controller) {
   // Flush the stream.
   controller.enqueue(this.container);
 }
}

function ascii_to_hexa(arr) {
 for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   arr[i] = Number(arr[i].charCodeAt(0)).toString(16);
 }
}
```

Comment: I am confused on what exactly the issue is and what you would expect to run differently

Comment: I'm trying to receive data messages that are comprised from ASCII and raw data and parsing it by '\r\n`, currently if the data messages consist of values that are not in ASCII table the the values are not displayed currently, for example :if I sent an [C0,OD,OA] I'll receive in my stream input ['fffd'] but the actual value is C0.

Comment: I haven't used transform streams before but it seems quite easy to write your own decoder, TextDecoderStream decodes utf-8 and replaces invalid chars with u+fffd (replacement char). So create a transformer that transforms bytes in the ascii range (1-127) to chars and leave the rest as is.